# Reverse biased diode

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, basic

What would be the voltmeter reading in the following circuit?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Image did not post successfully

Comment: what is `open diode of diode`?

Comment: I am not able to post image

Comment: Condition is like Diode is reverse biased & means anode is connected to negative terminal of source & cathode is connected to positive terminal of source,   Now i will remove the anode terminal connected to -Ve terminal of source ,  between anode and -ve terminal i will connect mutlimeter what will be the read voltage

Comment: use the schematic editor to insert a schematic

Comment: there is no expected voltage ... you did not say anything about the power supply

Comment: your question is like `if I fall from point A to point B, then will I get hurt?`

Comment: @Puneeth after clicking the small [edit] option below your question, can you see a dark icon showing two mountains in it? Click that followed by the `browse` option to add an image from your computer.

Comment: What's the input resistance of the meter? What's the leakage current of the diode, at the diode's present temperature?

Comment: Nothing. Its range switch is set to OFF.

Comment: Nice question... which makes you think... Why -1?

Answer (score 3):

For ideal components, the circuit is described by ill defined mathematical equations. The ideal diode when reverse biased will present infinite resistance. The ideal voltmeter also has infinite resistance. So the voltage division formula will be

\$V_{\text{voltmeter}} = \frac{\infty}{\infty + \infty}\$.

For realistic components, the volt meter would read some value which is highly dependent on the resistance presented by the two components.

### Load line for reversed biased diode not in break down region

[image: load line for reverse biased diode which is not in break down region]

If the volt meter shows 2.8V, your circuit is probably situated at the intersection of the two black lines. If there is a small change in the multimeter resistance, the voltage across the meter change. Blue line shows a multimeter with lower resistance. If the diode has higher reverse leakage current, that can also change the reading. Red line shows such a case.

Comment: Does the measured voltage only depend on leakage current of the diode and internal resistance of the meter or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes. That is what I would expect.

Comment: I am observing around 2.8V in multimeter please let me know whether it is correct or not

Comment: @Puneeth it depends on the input resistance of your multi meter and leakage current of diode. Repeat your experiment with different diodes (of same part number and different part number). I can't say if the result is *correct*.

Comment: Leakage current is 5uA, input resistance of multimeter  is of 150Kohm

Comment: Are these measured values or from a data sheet ? 5uA*150kohm gives only 0.7V, not 2.8.

Comment: [figure 2](https://neurophysics.ucsd.edu/courses/physics_120/Load%20line%20analysis%20for%20a%20diode%20circuit.pdf), [slide 18](https://www.slideshare.net/raaako2255/lecture5-diode-circuits-1), [9:45 in this video](https://slideplayer.com/slide/7245734/) show load line analysis for reversed biased diode. Quick web search indicates that load line diagrams for reversed biased diodes are few and mostly drawn for Zener diodes in break down region.

Comment: Re, "series" vs. "parallel" The volt meter _is_ connected "in parallel." Assuming that what the OP wants to measure is the open-circuit voltage of the string of three components; battery, resistor, and diode; then the diagram shows the meter connected "in parallel" with that string.

Comment: @Solomon Slow  Your observation is right. I will remove that statement in the next edit of the answer if OP post any update.

Comment: @Solomon Slow, With the same success you can say the voltmeter is connected "in series"... and it is connected exactly this way. Replace it with an ammeter. How is it connected? Again, "in series"... To say that an element is connected "in series" or "in parallel", we need at least three elements. Then we can say that two if them are connected "in series" or "in parallel" to the third. Two elements can be connected neither "in series" nor "in parallel"; they can be connected only "to each other". There is no name for this connection that is simpler than both "in series" and "in parallel".

Comment: … So, if the circuit was closed, the voltmeter could be connected "in parallel" only to the diode, resistor, source or to the combinations of adjacent elements 'diode + resistor', 'diode + source' and 'resistor + source'. Here three elements (the voltmeter, diode and resistor) are connected "in series" to the voltage source.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist No, two elements connected together at both ends are in series **and** in parallel. They meet our definition of series in that the current through them must be the same by virtue of how they are connected. They meet our definition of parallel in that the voltage across them must be the same by virtue of how they are connected. There is no need to fabricate an imaginary unnamed type of connection.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, Thanks for the clarification; it does not contradict to my explanations above. But I cannot find it on the web.  Is it your fabrication:)?  I hope you have a sense of humor... BTW I was worried about your absence lately and yesterday I looked for contacts on your profile page to write to you... but I did not find. Somehow I miss you with something that is not seen in others. This is strange because you have always been against me... and I cannot explain it to myself...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the effective diode impedance at some reverse voltage < Vbat and leakage current rating @ some -V and the ambient temperature as well as the diode type e.g. Schottky diodes leak more than Silicon.

Consider at some temp the Fairchild Semiconductor FDV303N has a reverse leakage of  0.1 microamp @ -1V. That would be equivalent to 10MOhm, thus the 1K is irrelevant and the DVM input impedance would read a voltage proportional to the sum of the two R’s * VBat.